# Removing a value from a cookie array

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I am trying to remove a value from a cookie array:-

```
  if (!empty($_GET['job_unfav'])) {

        $value_to_delete = $_GET['job_fav']; // Cookie value to delete from array
        $favouriteIDs = explode('|', $_COOKIE['job_fav']);

        var_dump($favouriteIDs);
        unset($favouriteIDs[$value_to_delete]);

        $favouriteIDs = array_values($favouriteIDs);

        setcookie('job_fav', implode('|', $favouriteIDs));

    }
```

`$favouriteIDs` returns:-

```
array(90) { 
      [0]=> string(3) "542" 
      [1]=> string(0) "" 
      [2]=> string(3) "538" 
      [3]=> string(0) "" 
      [4]=> string(3) "534" 
      [5]=> string(0) "" 
      [6]=> string(3) "524" 
      [7]=> string(0) "" 
      [8]=> string(3) "516" 
      [9]=> string(9) "undefined" 
      [10]=> string(9) "undefined" 
      [11]=> string(9) "undefined" 
      [12]=> string(3) "468" 
      [13]=> string(0) "" 
      [14]=> string(0) "" 
      [15]=> string(0) "" [16]=> string(0) "" [17]=> string(0) "" [18]=> string(0) "" [19]=> string(0) "" [20]=> string(0) "" [21]=> string(0) "" [22]=> string(3) "468" [23]=> string(0) "" [24]=> string(3) "235" [25]=> string(3) "231" [26]=> string(0) "" [27]=> string(0) "" [28]=> string(0) "" [29]=> string(3) "235" [30]=> string(3) "231" [31]=> string(3) "228" [32]=> string(0) "" [33]=> string(0) "" [34]=> string(0) "" [35]=> string(0) "" [36]=> string(3) "235" [37]=> string(3) "231" [38]=> string(0) "" [39]=> string(0) "" [40]=> string(0) "" [41]=> string(3) "231" [42]=> string(3) "228" [43]=> string(3) "225" [44]=> string(0) "" [45]=> string(0) "" [46]=> string(0) "" [47]=> string(0) "" [48]=> string(3) "235" [49]=> string(0) "" [50]=> string(0) "" [51]=> string(0) "" [52]=> string(0) "" [53]=> string(0) "" [54]=> string(0) "" [55]=> string(3) "235" [56]=> string(3) "235" [57]=> string(0) "" [58]=> string(3) "235" [59]=> string(0) "" [60]=> string(0) "" [61]=> string(3) "235" [62]=> string(0) "" [63]=> string(0) "" [64]=> string(0) "" [65]=> string(9) "undefined" [66]=> string(0) "" [67]=> string(9) "undefined" [68]=> string(0) "" [69]=> string(3) "502" [70]=> string(0) "" [71]=> string(0) "" [72]=> string(0) "" [73]=> string(0) "" [74]=> string(0) "" [75]=> string(0) "" [76]=> string(0) "" [77]=> string(0) "" [78]=> string(0) "" [79]=> string(0) "" [80]=> string(0) "" [81]=> string(0) "" [82]=> string(0) "" [83]=> string(0) "" [84]=> string(0) "" [85]=> string(0) "" [86]=> string(0) "" [87]=> string(0) "" [88]=> string(0) "" [89]=> string(3) "514" }
```

At the moment this isn't removing anything, any idea how to do this?

i.e. I would like to remove all occurences of '542' from `job_fav` cookie but keep all other values

Comment: Do you want to remove ALL occurances of `542` or just one?

Comment: All preferably @RiggsFolly

Comment: (1) You're testing `$_GET['job_unfav']` and using `$_GET['job_fav']`; (2) The way you're doing php is unseting the element which 542 is the *key*, not the *value*. You should use `unset($favouriteIDs[array_search($value_to_delete, $favouriteIDs)]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple method using the `array_search()` function.

```
<?php
$favoriteIds = array("542", "","538", "", "534", "", "524" );

$value_to_delete = '542';    //$_GET['job_fav']

$idx = array_search($value_to_delete, $favoriteIds);

if ( $idx !== FALSE ) {
    //if the value was found
    unset($favoriteIds[$idx]);
}

print_r($favoriteIds);
```

The results would be

```
Array
(
    [1] =>
    [2] => 538
    [3] =>
    [4] => 534
    [5] =>
    [6] => 524
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code your correctly remove the value you want from the array.

But,
In order to **override** the cookie you already have (so the value you remove is actually removed by exchanging the cookie) you need to add more params to the setcookie php function call you make:

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/es/function.setcookie.php):

> bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $**expire** = 0 [, string $**path** [, string $**domain** [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )

Make sure the params:

**path**

**domain**

Are equal than the cookie you already have, otherwise you will just create another one or the setcookie will be ignored.

Then the **expire** field (*which can be left as 0 if the cookie does not expire*) must be set with the current timestamp, you can get using the [time()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.time.php) function plus, the number of seconds you want the cookie to be active:

$expire = time() + *NUMBER_OF_SECONDS*

I hope this helps.